# Iterating (programmatically) over "all" integer polynomials (how to order them and when to stop to be sure we checked all what we wanted?)

Tags: polynomials, programming, invariance

I have some annoyingly stubborn problems that are basically of the form "are all integer polynomials of some kind a sum of a few products of polynomials of some other kind?". For instance I want a polynomial $P$ that is *not* of the form $P_1Q_1 + P_2Q_2$, where $P,P_i,Q_i$ have some easy to check property. Since I can't seem to get far using my wits alone, I was thinking I could try to write a simple program to find a polynomial that isn't of the desired form, so I have something concrete to work with.

However, I have no idea how to iterate over polynomials in such a way that I will be sure I've already checked all possibilities. Obviously I can limit the degree, but that still leaves me with infinitely many options.

What I'm hoping to find is some sort of semi-invariant $f$ that has finite equivalence classes, but also is (for example) superadditive and supermultiplicative. That way I could check all $P_i,Q_i$ with $f<n$ and be sure that any polynomial I didn't get which also has $f<n$ is not of the specified form.

Of course superadditivity and supermultiplicativity may not be the only options here, or perhaps I need to combine a few different semi-invariants, I only care about being able to stop iterating at some point.

If you want a specific problem: $P_i$ are of the form $2ax+6b$ modulo $x^2$, $Q_i$ are of the form $5cx+35d$ modulo $x^2$ ($a,b,c,d$ are integers). Find a $P$ such that $P$ is of the form $10ex+210f$ modulo $x^2$ and $P$ is *certainly not* of the form $P=P_1Q_1+P_2Q_2$. Of course it'd be great if the method worked for a wider range of problems of similar nature.

Comment: You probably want a generalization of Cantor's Diagonal argument, he provides a trick which allows us to map rational numbers (i.e. pairs of integers (a,b)) to single integers in a one-to-one fashion, in your case you want ot map tuples of integers (a,b,c,...) which are the coefficients of your polynomial to the integers. Then the natural "ordering" on the integers creates an ordering on your polynomials and furthermore gives you a scheme to iterate all polynomials with coefficients capped

Comment: this would probably make a good programming interview question, i will write an answer when i'm back online if someone doesn't beat me to it :)

Comment: @frogeyedpeas I mean, I could also cap the coefficients (and degree) directly - however, that doesn't work well with addition and multiplication. A $P$ with coefficients capped by some $n$ may easily be equal to $P_1Q_1+P_2Q_2$ with $P_i$ or $Q_i$ having way bigger coefficients. However, I will see if I can apply some modulo to both exponents and coefficients while preserving the properties I care about

Comment: If you don’t mind can you add to your question a very explicit mathematical statement of what you’re looking for.  Ex: “I want an algorithm/procedure such that given a finite set of P_i and Q_i, we find an integer polynomial P such that there does not exist integer polynomials u,v such that uP_i + vQ_i = P”

Comment: I realized the title of your question is asking for something very different than the question body’s

Comment: I've added an example problem, though it's exact form is not that important. How is the title disjoint from the body? I tried to concisely express my question and I think it's rather correct

Comment: Honestly your title is probably fine. My mistake was reading it, answering the title as a comment and then realizing the scope of your stuff is more subtle

Comment: I do realize it may seem like a much simpler question at first glance, yes. Unluckily, I need something far more strict than just iterating over some capped coefficients or a Monte Carlo program

Answer (score 1):

The scope of your question is not entirely clear to me.  Here are some possible interpretations and corresponding answers:

#### Is there an invariant that takes only finitely-many values on $\mathbb{Z}[x]$?

Yes, of course.  Take the invariant "is equal to the polynomial $x$".  This takes two values on $\mathbb{Z}[x]$: true and false.  If you want one that offers interesting insight your problem, you need to tell us what your problem is (it is unclear to me if your last paragraph is your problem or just an example).

#### ⟨ Your last paragraph ⟩

That is, does there exist $P(x)\in\mathbb{Z}[x]$ such that $P(0)=210$ and $P(x)$ cannot be written $$P(x)=a(x)\alpha(x)+b(x)\beta(x)$$ where \begin{gather*}
a(x)\equiv2u_ax+6v_a\pmod{x^2} \\
\alpha(x)\equiv5c_{\alpha}x+35d_{\alpha}\pmod{x^2}
\end{gather*} for some $u_a,v_a,c_{\alpha},d_{\alpha}$ and likewise for $b$ and $\beta$?

Of course.  Note that any such \begin{align*}
a(x)\alpha(x)+b(x)\beta(x)&\equiv2(u_ax+3v_a)\cdot5(c_{\alpha}x+7d_{\beta})+2(u_bx+3v_b)\cdot5(c_{\beta}x+7d_{\beta}) \pmod{x^2} \\
&=10(7u_ad_{\beta}+3v_ac_{\alpha}+7u_bd_{\beta}+3v_bc_{\beta})x \pmod{x^2,210}
\end{align*}  Since $10\mid 210$, the linear term is a multiple of $10$ even without the moduli.  But there are many polynomials for which $P(210)=0$, and the linear term is not a multiple of $10$; for example, $210+x$.

#### How can I write a program to iterate over all integer polynomials?

The idea is to find an computably-invertable invariant that takes on a recursively-enumerable set of values on $\mathbb{Z}[x]$.  When I had to do this, I used $$H\left(\sum_{j=0}^d{a_jf(x)}\right)=d+\sum_{j=0}^d{|a_j|}$$  This takes on every integer in $\mathbb{N}$.  Conversely, given a value $h$, I can find $H^{-1}(\{h\})$ quite easily:

```
For each d in [0,1,...,h]:
    Let a,b be arrays of d+1 integers
    Set b(-1)=0
    Comment:
        This is "stars-and-bars":
        We want to solve \sum_j{c_j}=h-d; then add signs
        It's easier to iterate over the partial sums \sum_{j=0}^J{c_j}
    For each 0<=b(0)<=b(1)<=b(2)<=...<=b(d)<=h+1:
        For each j in [0,1,2,...,d]:
            For each sign in [-1,1]:
                a(j)=sign*(b(j)-b(j-1))
        Compute with the polynomial a(0)+a(1)x+a(2)x^2+...+a(d)x^d
```

Comment: 1) You misunderstood - I don't want an invariant that takes finitely many values, but rather an invariant whose values are taken *finitely many each*. Sum of absolute values of coefficients would be an example (assuming we also cap the degree), but it doesn't seem to be compatible with multiplication and addition.  2) Something seems off about this reasoning (is the implication in the right direction?). Nonetheless, $x+210$ appears to be a correct solution which I somehow overlooked. Unluckily, this means that I need to slightly adjust the question and continue searching. Thank you though!

Comment: As for your invariant - it seems to have finite equivalence classes indeed, however it does not appear to behave well under addition or multiplication (primarily the former). Unless I'm missing something, I don't think I'd know when to end searching when trying to prove a given P cannot be represented in the given form.